# How to display color and size in a simple product in Magento

Tags: magento, colors, size, product

I'm developing a Magento store and I need to display the color and size of a  simple product in front end, is it possible?

I got it only with configurable product but not with simple product.

Something like this:
http://www.saiajustamodafesta.com.br/loja/vestido-longo-saia-justa.html

Anybody can help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your frontend/[your-package]/[Your-theme]/template/catalog/product/view.phtml file

```
$color = $_product->getColor();
<img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/'.$color.'.jpg'); ?>">
```

you need to upload jpg image same as color name ex red.jpg as well as same as size

Comment: Thanks, I used something like you told.

Answer (score 0):

Get color image attribute

```
    $color_code="color";
    $colorValue = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($_product->getId())->getData($color_code);
$swatchHelper=$objectManager->get("Magento\Swatches\Helper\Data");
$swatchData = $swatchHelper->getSwatchesByOptionsId([$colorValue]);

<img class="object-fit-contain w-100 h-100"  src="<?=
$objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface')
    ->getStore()
    ->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA).
'attribute/swatch'.$swatchData[$colorValue]['value']?>" alt="color"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

For Magento 2 if you have got quote item or a product object that is doesn't contain color attribute:

```
$product = $_item->getProduct();
$product->getResource()->load($product, $product->getId(),['color']);

//then you can get attribute data
$value = $product->getColor(); //52
$label = $product->getResource()->getAttribute('color')->getFrontend()->getLabel(); // Color
$text = $product->getResource()->getAttribute('color')->getFrontend()->getValue($product);  //Orange
```

Answer (score -1):

in your view.phtml getColor(); ?> replace with any attribute code, the important here is that the attribute must be on the catalog_product_flat tables, in order to do that, your attribute must be defined as "use_in_product_listing". Greetings.